# looping through an index and the previous item

Tags: python, loops, date, pandas

I would like to loop through a list of dates, in order to obtain the difference between a date and the date before (e.g. the difference between 4/13 and 3/13).

I'm looking for a for-loop able to scan thorugh couple of dates

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'date' : pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2017-03-30','2017-03-31','2017-04-03','2017-04-04'])),
'age': [10,np.nan,50,30]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['date','age'])

df1
```

input data

```
df2=df1.T


df2['new']=df2.iloc[:,3]-df2.iloc[:,2]
```

desidered result:

```
raw_data = {'date' : pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2017-03-30','2017-03-31','2017-04-03','2017-04-04'])),'age': [10,np.nan,50,30],
'diff': [10,-10,50,-20]}
output = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['date','age','diff'])

output
```

Comment: I'm very confused!

Comment: if you run the code until df2, you'll see that "new" is the difference in age between  2017-04-04 and  2017-04-03. I want to do a backward loop to go back into the previous dates,in couples, e.g. comparing also 2017-03-31 and 2017-03-30 by a loop

Comment: I really have trouble understand your question. Can you give a clear example of your input, your logic and your desired output?

Comment: I edited the text, putting input and desidered output dataframes. in the output the row "2017-04-04" has a diff value of -20, that is the difference between age on 2017-04-04 and age on 2017-04-03

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop if you want to know the difference between to dates.
Maybe you should do this:

```
df1['difference'] = (df1['date'] - df1['date'].shift(1)).apply(lambda x: pd.NaT if x is pd.NaT else x.days)
```

or this:

```
df1['difference'] = (df1['date'] - df1['date'].shift(-1)).apply(lambda x: pd.NaT if x is pd.NaT else x.days)
```

Comment: the difference is not between dates, but between ages, please look at desidered resutls, df3